# How to use NSTRACE when debugging

Tags: osx, debugging

I would like to use NSTRACE to see its built-in messages, and create new ones, at various locations within `nsterm.m`.  I imagine/guess that enabling NSTRACE needs to be done when configuring Emacs and it probably requires launching Emacs from the terminal and perhaps an interactive call such as `M-x trace-...`

**Q**:  How can I configure Emacs to enable NSTRACE and what other steps are needed to see the messages inside the terminal window?

---

For example, here is what I would use if I wanted to see the glyph debugging message inside `xdisp.c`:   I would use `--enable-checking='glyphs'` when configuring Emacs; then I would launch Emacs from the command line in a terminal; then I would type `M-x trace-redisplay` and I could see glyph debugging messages inside the terminal that are created inside `xdisp.c` like this:

```
#ifdef GLYPH_DEBUG
  debug_method_add (w, "This is my custom message.");
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `src/nsterm.h` (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/nsterm.h?id=3f938e1#n41):

```
/* ==========================================================================

   Trace support

   ========================================================================== */

/* Uncomment the following line to enable trace.

   Uncomment suitable NSTRACE_GROUP_xxx lines to trace more.

   Hint: keep the trailing whitespace -- the version control system
   will reject accidental commits. */

/* #define NSTRACE_ENABLED 1          */
```

And IMO, questions about development are best asked on `emacs-devel`.